# why is market clearing price assumed in cournot model with homogenous products

Tags: competitive-equilibrium

In the cornout model two firms choose the amount of a product they wish to produce. It is assumed that the price that results is the market clearing price for the total supply. Is there a justification for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] 
>    One way to interpret this result is to see our two-stage game as a mechanism to generate Cournot-like outcomes that dispenses with the mythical auctioneer.

A justification is given in [Kreps-Scheinkmann (1983)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3003636?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). They argue that this is the outcome if price competition follows production. For details see the linked article.